# Showing the value of an array?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
    $result = $mysqli->query(SELECT SUM(Answer) as answer FROM answers WHERE SID ='$uname'");
            $Sum = $result->fetch_row();
    var_dump($Sum);
?>
```

When executing the above code I get the following: `Array ( [SUM(Answer)] => 8 )`, however, when I try to access `$Sum[0]` I get the following Undefined offset: 0 and it prints nothing. I need to use this variable in an echo statement. Also, $Sum['Answer'] prints nothing, and I got a message saying undefined index Answer.

Comment: umm can you tell us something more then just giving us code and guessing whats going on?

Comment: *Obligatory:* The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: In addition to using the terribly outdated `mysql_query` method, it's not obvious that you're doing [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Can you advise more tadman, and thanks for the advise Jason. I'll read your post.

Comment: Jason, and tadman, I've updated my code showing mysqli. Could you advise more on the security and how to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to print the value of an array or object and show all of its members / properties, use the [`print_r`](https://www.php.net/print_r) function.

```
print_r($Sum);
```

or, for better formatting on a webpage:

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($Sum, true) . '</pre>';
```

---

After your edit: The var_dump is correct, you need to access your column by its name, like this:

```
$Sum['SUM(Answer)']
```

If you don't like this, change the name of your column (`SELECT SUM(Answer) AS sum FROM...` or something like that, then you can do `$Sum['sum']`).

Comment: Use `echo '<pre>' . print_r($result, true) . '</pre>';` for formatted output.

Comment: @MarkusHofmann I think I was making that edit at the same time that you were commenting it. :)

Comment: Looks like we were on the same wavelength.

Comment: I need the value to use it in an echo statement, print_r prints out the following array (size=1)
  'SUM(Answer)' => string '8' (length=1)

Comment: I know, that was in reference to your original question, if you need to echo it, just access it with `$Sum['SUM(Answer)']` like I said, or rename your column and access it that way.

Answer (score 4):

`mysql_fetch_assoc` returns an associative array, not a numeric array, so 0 will be an undefined index. PHP arrays do not automatically have numeric indices, unlike other languages.

If you want to use a numeric index, you should use [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) to get an array with both associative and numeric indices. If you need to stick with the associative array, however, you need to use the appropriate key:

```
$Sum['SUM(Answer)'];
```

The key is unusual because your SQL doesn't give SUM(Answer) a name so I would recommend that you update it to have one:

```
$SQL = "SELECT SUM(Answer) as answer FROM answers WHERE SID ='$uname' ";
```

Comment: Doesnt fetch assoc return both integers and field names?

Comment: No, `mysql_fetch_assoc` only returns an associative array: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Comment: I tried this, didn't work before. I should have added this to my question.

Comment: Uh ... `SELECT SUM(Answer) FROM` and then accessing the `Answer` column in the array won't work, you need to access the `SUM(Answer)` column.

Comment: @AhmedEbaid Read my answer, it will help you.

Comment: Your SQL query doesn't give that column a name, so the proper index is `SUM(Answer)`. updated my answer to address that.

Answer (score 0):

**TIP:** Always have a look in the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php).

The mysql_fetch_assoc() extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, because the MySQLi and PDO extensions should be used instead. [Just to quote the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)…

If you want to debug your code use:

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($result, true) . '</pre>';
```

This will echo the array / object formatted, so it'll be easier for you to read.

var_dump will be less readable as it shows types (e.g. string) and string length.

The [PHP Arrays Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) will teach you more on how to use arrays.

Happy reading :-)

Comment: Sorry, you're a bit late to the party, we're past the debug outputting at this point. :)

Comment: @spikex Had this answer in the editor a while, but got distracted (I died to go to the loo).